# Weird infinite rerender behaviour with nested dndkit SortableContext

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, dnd-kit

I'm currently trying to build a trello-like application with lists and tasks. I wanted to incorporate drag n drop functionality so I added the dndkit library. I've [managed](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/suspiciousRaccoon/dndkit-sortable-draggable-droppables/only-tasks?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522GIT%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy493xe00062a688ldylwtg%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy493xe00022a683gfceuph%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy493xe00042a6814d95r0n%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy493xe00052a682afm6z65%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsy493xe00022a683gfceuph%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy493xe00012a68jcq4o4jz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy493xe00022a683gfceuph%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsy493xe00012a68jcq4o4jz%2522%257D%252C%2522clsy493xe00052a682afm6z65%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy493xe00052a682afm6z65%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsyvy6e500132a65rago0llc%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522SETUP_TASKS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsyvy6e500132a65rago0llc%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clsy493xe00042a6814d95r0n%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy493xe00042a6814d95r0n%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsy4daqd00gy2a683rp1h7da%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy493xe00032a680tzfarij%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clsy46aoh000rdmgm6e945ax9%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522CSB_RUN_OUTSIDE_CONTAINER%253D1%2520devcontainer%2520templates%2520apply%2520--template-id%2520%255C%2522ghcr.io%252Fdevcontainers%252Ftemplates%252Fjavascript-node%255C%2522%2520--template-args%2520%27%257B%257D%27%2520--features%2520%27%255B%255D%27%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy4c1sf005u2a684rp4dxno%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy4daqd00gy2a683rp1h7da%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) to make the tasks sortable between the lists, and I would like to make the lists sortable aswell. However when I try to nest DndContext and SortableContext the application sometimes enters a weird recursive re-render loop and throws the following error repeatedly:

```
`Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`
```

The application then proceeds adds an `undefined` task into the data and fails when it maps over the data to re-render. I've tried logging to see where the error might be but I was only able to figure out the addition of the `undefined`, not the source of it or the re-render loop.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/suspiciousRaccoon/dndkit-sortable-draggable-droppables/tasks-and-lists?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522GIT%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy65dxz00062a68w9k0r6zr%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy65dxy00022a68gczekuk3%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy65dxy00042a6890wqhl46%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy65dxz00052a688hq6gpg8%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsy65dxy00022a68gczekuk3%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy65dxy00022a68gczekuk3%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy7wjl700022a68x0y9ai3q%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsy7wjl700022a68x0y9ai3q%2522%257D%252C%2522clsy65dxz00052a688hq6gpg8%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy65dxz00052a688hq6gpg8%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsy67pfw00hp2a68duwgagnb%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy67pfw00hp2a68duwgagnb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clsy65dxy00042a6890wqhl46%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy65dxy00042a6890wqhl46%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsy67lyu00el2a68dkiztd8w%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy65dxy00032a68x8r2z7me%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clsy46aoh000rdmgm6e945ax9%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522CSB_RUN_OUTSIDE_CONTAINER%253D1%2520devcontainer%2520templates%2520apply%2520--template-id%2520%255C%2522ghcr.io%252Fdevcontainers%252Ftemplates%252Fjavascript-node%255C%2522%2520--template-args%2520%27%257B%257D%27%2520--features%2520%27%255B%255D%27%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy66dwh003z2a68whpk8kwo%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsy67lyu00el2a68dkiztd8w%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) is the current code I have, and here the [repo](https://github.com/suspiciousRaccoon/dndkit-sortable-draggable-droppables) with both branches.

Here is a video demonstrating the issue:
https://imgur.com/a/HzRCK9B

Comment: The codesandbox is private so we can't access it :/

Comment: Oops. I've made the links public and added a link to the repo, also added a link with a video that shows the issue.